# A question about solving the nonlinear differential equation $\dot{x} = x(1-x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am aware of the standard solution that makes use of partial fractions. However, I made the following manipulations, in order to be more rigorous with splitting up the differentials before integration:

$$\dot{x} = f(x) = x(1-x)$$
$$\frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}t}\frac{1}{f(x)} = 1\quad\text{...definition of $\dot{x}$}$$
$$\int \frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}t}\frac{1}{f(x)}\;\textrm{d}t = \int 1\;\textrm{d}t$$
$$\int \frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}t}\frac{1}{f(x)}\;\textrm{d}t = t + K$$
$$\int \frac{\textrm{d}\ln{f(x(t))}}{\textrm{d}t}\;\textrm{d}t = t + K\quad\text{...observing Chain Rule}$$
$$\ln{f(x)} = t + K\quad\text{...fundamental theorem of calculus}$$
$$\ln{x(1-x)} = t + K\quad\text{...definition of $f(x)$}$$
$$\ln{x} + \ln{(1-x)} = t + K\quad\text{ERROR}$$

I have made an error somewhere, but I do not know where. Could you teach me?

Comment: At the left side, you have to integrate $\large \frac{1}{x(1-x)}$ and this is not $ln\ x(1-x)$, but $ln\frac {x}{1-x}$

Comment: @Peter: Actually, even that is not quite correct. Note the DE has two stationary solutions $x \equiv 0$ and $x \equiv 1$. The other solutions can't cross these (by uniqueness theory) so, for non stationary solutions, one of the three alternatives $[x(t) < 0, \ \forall t]$, $[0 < x(t) < 1, \ \forall t]$, $[x(t) >1, \ \forall t]$ holds. Which of these is satisfied depends on the initial conditions. Depending which holds, $\frac{1}{x(1-x)}$ is either always positive or always negative. This sign will affect the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x(1-x)}$.

Comment: @Peter Sure, that's why I know there is an error. Can you pick out where the error originates from in the steps though?

Comment: The antiderivate of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is not $ln\ f(x)$. The chain rule would give the derivate $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$.

Comment: @Peter I did not write that the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is $\ln{f(x)}$, but instead that the antiderivative of $\frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}t}\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is $\ln{f(x)} = \ln{f(x(t))}$.

Comment: @user89: $\frac{d}{dt} \ln (f(x)) = \frac{dx}{dt} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} ln(f(x)) = \frac{dx}{dt} \cdot\frac{1}{f(x)} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}  f(x) = \frac{dx}{dt} \cdot\frac{1}{f(x)} \cdot (1- 2x)$.

Comment: @MikeF Thanks! That was helpful. So I think my conceptual block lay in assuming that $\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{\textrm{d}f(x)}{\textrm{d}x}$ -- I was missing an application of the chain rule. Thanks so much!